# Can I apply a Limitation to Extra Fatigue?

Tags: gurps-4e

Many Advantages can have Limitations, which reduce the point cost of the Advantage in return for limiting how, when, or on what it can be used (for instange, Magery can have Aspected, One College, etc.).  I'm not where I can access my rule books at present, but it just occurred to me to ask: can I apply a limitation (such as "Magic Only", as already found on Wild Talent) on Extra Fatigue?

The underlying idea is to create a very small (SM -2 at least) Mage who can still cast large spells.  I've seen this done with Pixies (in 3rd Ed., don't know if it crossed over to 4th), but I don't recall how it was done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. It's mentioned specifically in GURPS Magic, page 15, which reads in part:

> Fatigue Points may be bought with the limitation
>   “Usable only for spellcasting,” worth -10%.

Note it's not a very big discount, probably because spellcasting is arguably the prime application of fatigue for mages. However you can get some other character disadvantage points for being tiny and/or fragile, etc.

Comment: If I were at home, I'd have just looked this up.  However, if you follow full combat rules, everyone uses fatigue for combat, and a number of physical activities use fatigue as well -- plus, Martial Arts (at least in Dungeon Fantasy) use fatigue for *ki* powered actions like Power Blow.

Comment: @ZeissIkon I don't follow. Did you mention that to suggest that the value listed is too low because there are other such uses of fatigue?

Comment: Not primarily, I was just thinking it might be more like 25%.  Really, though, spellcasters are the ones most likely to use *enough* fatigue to want this (cast Grease to cover a room, and you're exhausted!), those other uses aren't as likely to consume enough to debilitate.  I'd bet it was playtested enough thousands of hours to have confidence in the published rules.

Comment: Yes. Having played GURPS since it came out (and its ancestor TFT before that), I'd say you're right and that's what I was thinking in mentioning my guess why it's not a big discount. Spellcasting fatigue rules and point costs have been thoroughly playtested and discussed (and still are) ever since the first edition of GURPS Magic. However as with all points in GURPS, there's a limit to applying one measure (points) to so many different things. There are many valid ways to think of and assess points, and all of them have limits and apply differently in different situations.